# Slick Carousel - Images stuck in vertical when browsing inside a modal tab/window

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, slick.js

I am using Slick carousel with modal content. Everything works fine but when trying to browse from one project to another with prev/next handlers inside the open tab/window. Images stuck in vertical.

```
<section>
  <div>
   <a data-open="first-project" class="card cell aos-init" data-aos="slide-up" aria-controls="project-1" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0">
    <div><img src="first-project-1.jpg"></div>
   </a>
  </div>

 <div>
  <a data-open="second-project" class="card cell aos-init" data-aos="slide-up" aria-controls="project-1" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0">
   <div><img src="second-project-1.jpg"></div>
  </a>
 </div>
</section>

<div class="reveal modal" id="first-project" data-reveal data-close-on-click="true" data-animation-in="slide-in-right" data-animation-out="slide-out-right" data-resize="first-project">

    <div><a data-open="second-project"><span>Next </span><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a></div>

      <div class="carousel">
       <div><img src="first-project-1.jpg"></div>
       <div><img src="first-project-2.jpg"></div>
       <div><img src="first-project-3.jpg"></div>
       <div><img src="first-project-4.jpg"></div>
      </div>

<a class="close-button close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close" data-close <span aria-hidden="true">X</span></a>
</div>

<div class="reveal modal" id="second-project" data-reveal data-close-on-click="true" data-animation-in="slide-in-right" data-animation-out="slide-out-right" data-resize="second-project">

     <div><a data-open="first-project"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i> <span class="pr-txt">Previous</span></a></div>

  <div class="carousel">
    <div><img src="second-project-1.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="second-project-2.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="second-project-3.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="second-project-4.jpg"></div>
  </div>
```

X

```
$(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  var modal = $(this);
$('.carousel').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  infinite: true,
  arrows:true,
  nextArrow: '<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i',
  prevArrow: '<i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i',
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  speed: 1500,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll:1  
 });
});

$(document).on('closed.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  var modal = $(this);
  $('.carousel').slick('unslick');
});
```

Probably the issue is because of 'unslick', but I have to use it in order to keep sliders working properly when open the modal window. Without 'unslick', carousel doesn't load properly (sometimes it shows fast, sometimes takes a bit to show sliders).

Thanks.

Comment: What you provided is not enough. It is unclear what versions jQuery, Bootstrap (if the modal you talk about is a Bootstrap one - if not, what type of modal are you using?), and Slick  you use. It would be best if you created a [mcve] here, in the question, using the `<>` button (and adding all the necessary assets, including links to your images or placeholders for them). Without the above we can only guess what you're talking about.

Comment: You want to open a modal and the modal should have a slick carousel inside it?

Comment: I have several modals with its respective slick carousel inside. What I want is to be able to browse through modals using 'previous/nex' data-open handlers. If you see the example url above (just with two modals), once a modal is open, after clicking on 'previous/next' to go to the other modal, carousel images inside it stuck in vertical. Error displayed: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null". Sorry if my explanation is not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
 $('.carousel').slick(...)
```

with

```
$('.carousel', this).slick(...)
```

which will only target the `.carousel` inside your current modal, which is referenced by `this` in the reveal callback.

Also, it might be a good idea to destroy the slick on modal `close`, not on `closed` (it's better to destroy it while the modal is being closed, not after it has been closed). If it gets destroyed too soon, leave it on `closed`.

---

Do note you have serious markup issues (i.e.: your link `src` attributes are not closed). You probably want to run your code through a HTML validator until you fix all validation issues.

After that, the following should work:

```js
$(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  $('.carousel', this).slick({
    autoplay: true,
    infinite: true,
    arrows:true,
    nextArrow: '<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i',
    prevArrow: '<i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i',
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    speed: 1500,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll:1  
  });
}).on('close.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  $('.carousel', this).slick('unslick');
});
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help. Sorry for the markup (my eyes really tired today). Finally I had to leave it on modal 'closed'.

Comment: Hey Andrei! Sorry to bother. Regarding tablets/phones, I realized the fix is working well with Android devices, but on ios devices sometimes carousel images show after 1-2 seconds. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @user2687676 none whatsoever. Not much of an iUser, or an iFan, for that matter. But sounds like something you need to take up to either Slick author or Apple. Typically, the bar is set at: *"works"*. Not at *"works great"*, when it comes to sliders compatibility with mobile devices, unless you're using one designed for a specific platform, which usually doesn't perform so well on the others.

Comment: What I can tell you is that currently, the industry standard for production environments, when performance is an issue, is to use different libraries for different platforms and simply render based on device.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!